# Variable Assignment Issue for Multiple dynamic SQL in DB2 Iseries

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, iseries-navigator

We are using DB2 Iseries V7R3 on AS400 system. 
In one of the stored procedure, we are preparing dynamic SQL queries. Each SQL query is assigned to different variables. When we execute the stored procedure sometimes it fails but when retry with same parameters it works. 
Upon putting logs in the stored procedure, we have observed that during the failed cases value used for variable 2 is from variable 1.

Attached is the stored procedure and screenshot of the logs.

Appreciate any help on this, running out of the thinking options for this.

However, sometimes it uses select * for variable1 as well. After retry it works ok.

```html
 create stored procedure (
)DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
LANGUAGE SQL 
SPECIFIC SYMDTA.PRC_RETRIEVE_CLAIM_LIST 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
COMMIT ON RETURN YES 
CONCURRENT ACCESS RESOLUTION USE CURRENTLY COMMITTED 
SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
COMMIT = *NONE , 
DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
SRTSEQ = *HEX   
BEGIN 

DECLARE DATACLAIM CLOB ( 1048576 ) DEFAULT ' ' ; 
DECLARE GCLAIMCOUNT CLOB ( 1048576 ) DEFAULT ' ' ; 

DECLARE CR_CLAIM_LIST_STMT CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR CLM_DATA_STMT ; 
DECLARE CR_CLAIM_COUNT_STMT CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR CLM_COUNT_STMT ; 

SET DATACLAIM = 'SELECT * FROM  table ';
SET GCLAIMCOUNT = 'select count(*) from table';

INSERT INTO  DEBUGGING_DYNAMIC_QUERIES VALUES ( POLICY_NO , DATACLAIM , CURRENT TIMESTAMP , 'DATACLAIM' ) ; 
INSERT INTO  DEBUGGING_DYNAMIC_QUERIES VALUES ( GCLAIMCOUNT , CURRENT TIMESTAMP , 'GCLAIMCOUNT' ) ; 
PREPARE CLM_DATA_STMT FROM DATACLAIM ; 
OPEN CR_CLAIM_LIST_STMT ; 
  


PREPARE CLM_COUNT_STMT FROM GCLAIMCOUNT ; 
OPEN CR_CLAIM_COUNT_STMT ; 
FETCH CR_CLAIM_COUNT_STMT INTO TOTAL_RECORDS_G4 ; 
CLOSE CR_CLAIM_COUNT_STMT ;
```

Output the debug table :-

Wrong :- 
DATACLAIM = "select * "  - 2020-01-01 11:00 AM
GCLAIMCOUNT = "Select * " - 2020-01-01 11:01 AM

After retry :- 
DATACLAIM = "select * "  - 2020-01-01 12:00 pm
GCLAIMCOUNT = "Select count(*) " - 2020-01-01 12:01 Pm

Comment: The problem with this question is that no one wants to look at your giant data dump. In fact, it already has a close vote. Trim it down to the smallest version of your code that exhibits the problem. Be sure to include table definitions and sample data (If we can't run it on our machines, we can't help you). Also include the error code or bad result you are seeing along with what you expect to see.

Comment: Done the changes, Removed the entire code. Just now a sample. table definition anything can be used. It happens sometimes only. not sure how can we simulate this.